# Reshaping a vector into a larger matrix with arbitrary m and n

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I'm attempting to create a function that takes a vector of any length and uses its entries to generate a matrix of size mxn, where m and n are arbitrary numbers. If the matrix has a greater number of entries that the original vector, the entries should repeat. E.g. A vector, (1,2,3,4) would make a 3x3 matrix (1,2,3;4,1,2;3,4,1).

So far I have this function:

```
function A = MyMatrix(Vector,m,n)

A = reshape([Vector,Vector(1:(m*n)-length(Vector))],[m,n]);

end
```

which is successful in some cases:

```
>> m=8;n=5;Vector=(1:20);
>> A = MyMatrix(Vector,m,n)

A =
     1     9    17     5    13
     2    10    18     6    14
     3    11    19     7    15
     4    12    20     8    16
     5    13     1     9    17
     6    14     2    10    18
     7    15     3    11    19
     8    16     4    12    20
```

However this only works for values of m and n that multiply to a number less than or equal to twice the number of entries in 'Vector', so 40 in this case. When mn is larger than 40, this code yields:

```
>> m=8;n=6;Vector=(1:20);
>> A = MyMatrix(Vector,m,n)
Index exceeds the number of array elements (20).

Error in MyMatrix (line 3)
A = reshape([Vector,Vector(1:(m*n)-length(Vector))],[m,n]);
```

I have tried to create a workaround using functions such as `repmat`, however, so far I have not been able to create a matrix with larger m and n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to

- index the vector using "[modular](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html)", 1-based indexing;
- [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) it taking into account that Matlab is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so you need to swap `m` and `n`;
- [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) to swap `m` and `n` back.

```
V = [10 20 30 40 50 60]; % vector
m = 4; % number of rows
n = 5; % number of columns
A = reshape(V(mod(0:m*n-1, numel(V))+1), n, m).';
```

This gives

```
A =
    10    20    30    40    50
    60    10    20    30    40
    50    60    10    20    30
    40    50    60    10    20
```